# How to reuse (extend) bootstrap css classes in rails/sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I @import "boostrap" in core.scss file which also import other scss files (e.g.: _modals.css).

In modals.css I want to extend some bootstrap classes:

```
.modal-container {
  @extend .row;
}
```

And extend does not work as expected:

> WARNING on line 42 of
>   ....../_modals.css.scss:
>   ".row" failed to @extend ".row".   The selector ".row" was not found. 
>   This will be an error in future releases of Sass.   Use "@extend .row
>   !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.

- The only way I made it work is to @import "bootstrap" again in
  _modals.scss but this actually includes the whole bootsrap inside this file...

  The other solution is to move all definitions which extends css in
  core.css file - in this case - css in much less structured ...

How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was because I also imported files via sass require/require_tree command.

```
 *= require_tree ./autoinclude
```

If all files are imported via @import function, everything works!

```
@import "autoinclude/*";
```

Answer (score 0):

The .row has to be in the same file somewhere in the previous lines of code.

@extend is not that good and you can't use it within media queries,
if you overuse it you will end up introducing inconsistencies on the code.

define a mixin in another file and use @import instead