# Selector not found when @extending bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

I'm starting my first rails project. In this project I will be using Bootstrap and SASS. I want to avoid (for the most part) putting style-related classes into my HTML, as explained in this post:

[Using Sass To Semantically @extend Bootstrap](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/)

I have included bootstrap-sass in my project using Bower and following the instructions here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#bower-with-rails

Now bootstrap itself is working, since I can use its classes in my HTML and everything renders just fine. But if I try to extend one of my classes with a Bootstrap class, for example:

```sass
.myClass
  @extend .text-muted
```

Then I get the following error:

```
".myClass" failed to @extend ".text-muted".
The selector ".text-muted" was not found.
Use "@extend .text-muted !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

I guess it might have something to do with my Sass files being loaded before Bootstrap but I don't know what to do.

The following is the content of my `application.css.sass` file, in which some things are `*= require`d and others are `@import`ed (I'm not sure whether this is how things should be done).

```sass
/*
 *= require components-font-awesome
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
$icon-font-path: "bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/"
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: @cimmanon sorry, I'm new to Sass and I don't understand how my question relates to that other. Should I be compiling only one `.sass` file and including the others as partials?

Comment: Try it and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: @cimmanon No it doesn't. Besides `application.css.sass` I have only one stylesheet file, `schedule.sass`. I've tried renaming it to `_schedule.sass` but the problem persists.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828313/how-to-reuse-extend-bootstrap-css-classes-in-rails-sass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bootstrap-Sass doc suggests to remove the requires from your `application.sass`, as you "will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables."

You should remove

```
*= require_tree .
```

and make sure to `@import` all relevant files (you seem to do that already).

`require_tree` will automatically include all stylesheets below your `app/assets/stylesheet/` folder and will certainly provoke some duplication or even a wrong load order. instead gain control by importing the files 'manually' in the desired order.

Now `@extend` either inside the `application.sass` or in a different partial that you `@import` after the bootstrap files and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

### Rails 5 and Rails 6 Answer for `failed to @extend` and `Undefined variable` from `SassC::SyntaxError`

TL;DR: Rails 5 and 6 use a `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file that by default processes all the `.scss` files in the root folder `app/assets/stylesheets`, whereas Rails 4 only targeted files imported in `application.scss`. To fix these errors in Rails 5 & 6, either:

1. Move your SCSS files from the `stylesheets` directory to a subdirectory of stylesheets, since `.scss` files in subdirectories are not processed by default.
2. Modify the `manifest.js` file to only process entry files, such as application.scss.

[Link to relevant documentation in Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs).

#### Extended explanation

To reproduce this error, run: `bin/rails assets:precompile` in the terminal. You will receive an error message such as:

```
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: ".badge-title" failed to @extend ".text-center".
       The selector ".text-center" was not found.
       Use "@extend .text-center !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 47:11 of app/assets/stylesheets/badges.scss
```

My `application.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "badges";
// All bootstrap overrides go above
@import "bootstrap";
```

Note: badges.scss expected the CSS `.text-center` to be defined within the first @import statement above, however Sprockets 5+ is processing all the files in the stylesheets directory, **even if the file name has a leading underscore**.

To fix:

1. I moved `stylesheets/badges.scss` to `stylesheets/components/badges.scss`
2. Modified line 2 in my application.scss file to, `@import "components/badges.scss`

Hope this helps someone!